# Identify an Office file write operation on Dokan file system

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-word, dokan

I'm using dokan as a file system and don't know how to identify office file write operation. Specially the lock and temp files.
I have to identify them because only the main file has to upload to an external database.

Theoretically I get office word to work but this is more a workaround. I hope there is a special attribute to identify there temp files.

Regard Chris

Comment: FileSystemWatcher class?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ProccessId to see if its Office's proccess. Check if the filename matches temp file. Some Office versions call CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_TEMPORARY and som set it later in SetAttributes. The best way is delay file upload till Cleanup and even then you can add an timer to uplosd it couple of seconds later. (Not sure but I think I remember that OpenOffice closes temp file and then opens it again to call MoveFile).
Hope it helps.